# Apache CXF 3.2.7 LoggingFeature configuration

Tags: apache, logging, soap, cxf

I'm setting up a webservice client using Apache CXF v3.2.7 .  I've added to my cxf.xml in the jaxws:client the LoggingFeature

```
   <jaxws:features>
     <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingFeature"/>
  </jaxws:features>
```

I'm trying to view the SOAP message in the console when attempting to connect to a remote webservice in order to figure out why the connection is timing out.  I'm not sure what else to add to the webservice client in order to see this. Any suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: Same problem here.